# In rails render an action method from a view of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to achieve following: I have a Project edit page, on which I show fields to edit project details.

Below that I show the list of tasks assigned to this project.

```
<h1>Editing Project</h1>

<%= render 'form', project: @project %>

<%= render '/project_tasks/index', action: 'index', controller: 'ProjectTasks' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @project %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

As seen above,  I'm trying to invoke action method named "index" of controller 'ProjectTasks'

Below is code of ProjectTasks controller :

```
   class ProjectTasksController < ApplicationController

      def index

          @project_clients = ProjectTask.all
          @myname='xyz'
          render :partial
      end

    end
```

And text of partial view :  \views\project_tasks_index.html.erb

```
<h1> Im partial : my name is  <%= @myname%></h1>
```

Output I get is :
{edit form fields + } and below that following text from partial view

```
Im partial : my name is
```

As seen "xyz", the value of instance varaible is not printed.

After some research I found, my code directly renders view, without calling the action method. Is this not supported in rails?

I'm from asp.net mvc background and this is achievable in asp.net as follows:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("ProjectUserList", new { projectId = Model.Id }); }
```

Pasting just to make my point more clear, what it does is, it executes method instead of directly rendering view.

Just to summarize, what I expect is

edit.html.erb -> calls render action from project_tasks controller -> I set there @myname -> it then renders partial view -> view displays @myname value.

I dont' want to set @myname in edit method of project controller, instead its set in index method of project_tasks controller. This way my edit view or action doesn't know what data partial view requires, its the responsibility of partial method to supply that data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> In rails An Action is a controller method **and** page template

so here corresponding to your `index` action you should have `index.html.erb` page template

```
   class ProjectTasksController < ApplicationController
      def index
          @project_clients = ProjectTask.all
          @myname='xyz'
      end
    end
```

and in `views/project_tasks/index.html.erb` you can get value of `@project_clients` and `@myname`

you can follow [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-views-and-controllers/) for more clarity.

Comment: main issue here is I set @myname in the index method of project_tasks controller, and I invoke render this partial from edit view. When this happens, it directly invokes partial view, and as I don't set variables in edit method, partial view doens't get this value. I have updated my question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

> Do not use instance variable inside partial, which make tight coupling with controller action and is a bad practice. Instead pass those data as locals.

**In any controller**

```
render partial: 'your_partial', locals: { myname: @myname }
```

**In view**

```
<h1> Im partial : my name is  <%= myname %></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **render** does not call action methods of controllers instead it directly renders html.erb. So before rendering screen you need to ensure all dependent variables are calculated and initialized.

To solve this you can make use of AJAX which renders list of project tasks on load of Edit project screen.

```
#project_tasks/edit.html.erb
<h1>Editing Project</h1>

<%= render 'form', project: @project %>

<div id='project_task_listing'></div>

<%= link_to 'Show', @project %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
        //make ajax request to action: 'index', controller: 'ProjectTasks' and in response update div with id 'project_task_listing'
    });
  });
<script>
```

Comment: Yes, only two options either initialize variables on rendering page edit page or use ajax to make request to controller and action which renders the list.